# How to remove or unset style from css class?

Tags: css

I'm using CSS framework, and there is a CSS class in it, for example, `.btn-trigger`. This class has many styles, `opacity`, `font-size`, etc. One of these styles is breaking my animation. How can remove this style?

Comment: Use google console to detect which style is breaking your animation and override it using your own class.

Comment: Provide a fiddle or link to ur site

Comment: your question should be... _I am using **this** framework..here is my **css** for that button...here is my **css** for animation....what is the issue...?_

Comment: @Bhuwan, it's a general question,  not framework specific

Answer (score 2):

```css
.sub {
  background:red;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.sub {
  all: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">Hello</div>
</div>
```